# How to align divs to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a cityHeader(in this pic it is Los Angeles).
Underneath cityHeader there is div called weatherMain which contains three smaller divs(id=temperature,id=weatherDescriptionHeader and id=documentIconImg

```css
   

 #cityHeader {
      float: right;
      display: block;
      margin: 5px;
      font-size: 42px;
      font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 

     }

    #weatherMain {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      text-align: right;
    }

    #weatherMain div {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    #weatherDescriptionHeader {
      font-size: 28px;
      vertical-align: 50%;
    }

    #temperature {
      font-size: 38px;
      vertical-align: 25%;
    }
```

```html
<h1 id="cityHeader"></h1>
     <div id="weatherMain">
              <div id="temperature"></div>
              <div id="weatherDescriptionHeader"></div>
              <div><img id="documentIconImg" /></div>
            </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nueu.jpg)documentIconImg).
Three smaller divs should be under cityHeader, positioned next to each other and all aligned to the right.
I tried floating them to the right,adding text-align:right to their parent element(weatherMain), nothing works. 
In the pic temperature div is 9 degrees,weatherDescriptionHeader is Clear sky and documentIconImg is icon.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for: https://codepen.io/dillonbrannick/pen/XOoNjp

I added in the background colours just so it's easy to identify the elements. Just put your background image into the #weatherMain and remove the other background colours and it should work fine. I added in a margin to #weathermain just to display it within the middle of the page.

Also I added a margin:0 to the h1 tag as h1 automatically adds some css style to it that was interfering.

HTML:

```
<div id="weatherMain">
    <h1 id="cityHeader">Hello World</h1>
    <div id="temperature">Howya</div>
    <div id="weatherDescriptionHeader">Hola</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#weatherMain {
  background-color:red;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 10% 20% 10% 20%
}
#cityHeader {
  background-color:yellow;

 }
h1{
  margin:0;
  font-size:45px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida   Grande", sans-serif; }

#temperature {
  background-color:green;
  font-size: 38px;
}
#weatherDescriptionHeader {
  background-color:lightblue;
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

Comment: I took your code, made some adjustments and in the end i got what i wanted.Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#weatherMain {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  float: right
}
```

Comment: I did, it s not working.I don t know if i have to add position:absolute to div which contains both cityHeader and weatherMain .If that has anything to do with these divs not rendering properly.